# Make number of B-spline basis functions match the number of abscissae for odd degree

Tags: splines

For a given number of abscissae $x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n$, I am working with B-splines $B_{j,p}(x)$ of odd degree $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

In the simplest case $p=1$, the functions are piecewise linear, thus for each abscissae $i$ there results one $B_{j,p}$; or colloquially speaking: $j=i$.

But in the more general case, on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ abscissae, there seem to result $q=n+2\cdot(p-1)$ basis functions, i.e., $j$ ranges from $1$ to $q$.

How can I achieve that I obtain $n$ basis functions for $n$ abscissae for arbitrary prescribed $p$, that satisfy all the usual conditions (given below just to prevent an argument on what is usual):

1. partition of unity
2. exact matching end-point
3. member of Sobolev space $W^{p,\infty}$
4. convergence of an interpolation between neighboring degrees $p$ in the limit of abscissae density.